# Running two PowerShell Scripts in Winform C# using PowerShell RunSpace I get the same results

Tags: c#, powershell, winforms, runspace

Using Visual Studio 2017
WIN-Form C#

When I run the following PowerShell Scripts in Winform C# using a PowerShell RunSpace I get the same results.

```
Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | Select-Object DisplayName | Format-Table –AutoSize > C:\Temp\InstalledSoftwareList1.txt

Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* |  Select-Object DisplayName | Format-Table –AutoSize > C:\Temp\InstalledSoftwareList2.txt
```

But, if I run those same scripts in **PowerShell ISE**, I get two different results, which is what is desired.

I can’t figure out why running them in WinForms brings back the same results.

This is what I am using in the Winform.

```
private string RunScript(string script)
    {
        Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
        runspace.Open();
        Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
        pipeline.Commands.AddScript(script);
        pipeline.Commands.Add("Out-String");
        Collection<PSObject> results = pipeline.Invoke();
        runspace.Close();
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (PSObject pSObject in results)
            stringBuilder.AppendLine(pSObject.ToString());
        return stringBuilder.ToString();
    }
```

and running the code like this.

```
RunScript(@"Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | Select-Object DisplayName | Format-Table –AutoSize > C:\Temp\InstalledSoftwareList1.txt");

RunScript(@"Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* |  Select-Object DisplayName | Format-Table –AutoSize > C:\Temp\InstalledSoftwareList2.txt");
```

Any suggestion?

Regards,

Comment: Make sure you compile the hosting C# application for x64 (eg. _not_ using the AnyCPU or x86 profiles)

Answer (score 0):

As Mathias R. Jessen suggested, I compile the C# application for x64 and now the scripts returns two different result.